# For Each availability zone within an AWS region

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, subnet, cidr

I am trying to create a subnet within the availability zones within a region using Terraform. I have the below code and am having some trouble getting my subnet to read into the availability zone for the region. Below is also my error.

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {
  state = "available"
}
locals {
  az_names = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  for_each   = var.environment
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr

  tags = {
    Name = var.vpc_tags
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each                = var.public_sub_cidr
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main[each.key].id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 0, each.value.public_subnet)
  availability_zone       = local.az_names[each.key]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_tags}-PubSubnet"
  }
}
```

**Errors**

```
Error: Unsupported attribute



on vpc.tf line 17, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
  17:   cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 0, each.value.public_subnet)
    |----------------
    | each.value is ""

This value does not have any attributes.

Error: Invalid index



on vpc.tf line 18, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
  18:   availability_zone       = local.az_names[each.key]
    |----------------
    | each.key is ""
    | local.az_names is list of string with 3 elements

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number
is required.
```

Any advice on reading from availability zones and also assigning these public subnets would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I made some progress, updated my code to use for each with the "length" of my data resource. See code below and error:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each                = length(local.az_names)
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.tableau[each.key].id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, each.value)
  availability_zone       = local.az_names[each.key]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_tags}-PubSubnet"
  }
}
Error: Invalid for_each argument



 on vpc.tf line 15, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
  15:   for_each                = length(local.az_names)

The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument
must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type
number.

make: *** [apply] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but this is incorrect:

```
for_each                = length(local.az_names)
```

it should be:

```
for_each                = toset(local.az_names)
```

Since `local.az_names` is set now, you can only use `each.key` (`each.value` will be same as `each.key`). For example:

```
availability_zone       = each.key
```

The following code creates a subnet in each AZ:

```
provider "aws" {
  # your details
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {
  state = "available"
}

locals {
  az_names = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names
}

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each                = {for idx, az_name in local.az_names: idx => az_name}
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, each.key)
  availability_zone       = local.az_names[each.key]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Marcin. What I am trying to do is create a subnet for each availability within a aws region. I am having some trouble getting the cidr blocks to attach to the public subnet. I am working with the cidrsubnet function in order to dynamically attach this value, but am not sure how to do so when dealing with for_each

Comment: @DaveMichaels Hi. I added a code that correctly creates a subnet in each available AZ with an example.